# Problems installing truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-compile

I've installed truffle multiple times, uninstall and installed again, all I get is command not found

```
npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated apollo-datasource@3.3.2: The `apollo-datasource` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-base@3.7.2: The `apollo-server-plugin-base` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-types@3.8.0: The `apollo-server-types` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-errors@3.3.1: The `apollo-server-errors` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server@3.12.0: The `apollo-server` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-express@3.12.0: The `apollo-server-express` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-env@4.2.1: The `apollo-server-env` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/utils.fetcher` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated apollo-reporting-protobuf@3.4.0: The `apollo-reporting-protobuf` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/usage-reporting-protobuf` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/ens@0.4.5: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-core@3.12.0: The `apollo-server-core` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023 and October 22nd 2024, respectively). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/resolver@0.2.4: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts

added 825 packages in 2m

107 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
dell@bytecypher:~$ truffle init
truffle: command not found
dell@bytecypher:~$ truffle -v
truffle: command not found
```

Please guys what do I do next

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx`: If you're having trouble with the global installation, you can try using **`npx truffle init`** instead of *`truffle init`* or `npm install -g truffle`. The npx command allows you to run packages that are not globally installed.

use `yarn` : **`yarn global add truffle`**